# Как сделать перенос слов по слогам для кирилицы Flutter

Tags: flutter, textview, flutter-ui, перенос-слов

Как сделать перенос слов по слогам для кирилицы Flutter?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте пакет https://pub.dev/packages/auto_hyphenating_text
не знаю работает ли он с кирилицей